# Unable to access local environment variable using Python in AWS Cloud9 IDE

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide

I'm using the AWS Cloud9 IDE to develop a lambda function but I'm unable to access environment variables that I'm using to store external API keys. Here is the code I'm running

```
import os

def getKeyValue(key):
    key_value =  os.environ[key]
    return key_value
```

and the error when I pass data to the lambda function locally from the IDE -

```
'PEPPERJAM_KEY': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/fh/lambda_function.py", line 9, in lambda_handler
    result = pj.getKeyValue('PEPPERJAM_KEY')
  File "/var/task/fh/pj_utils.py", line 4, in getKeyValue
    api_key =  os.environ[key]
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PEPPERJAM_KEY'
```

I have set the environment variable in `.bashrc`, when I type `env` in the terminal I see it listed, I have also restarted the EC2 instance but still get this same issue.

Any ideas on what I could be missing? When I run it remotely, it works (I'm assuming because I have the variable set in the Environment variables section in the AWS Lambda settings, so it's definitely just the IDE local environment that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add value of the environment variable to your template.yml file (present in the venv folder) as described in [Using the AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html#serverless_app_resources) article, so under

```
Properties:
  .... # tons of other properties here, add yours at the end
  Environment:
    Variables:
      PEPPERJAM_KEY: 'This is my awesome value'
```

See also screenshot below for the e2e function, template.yaml and result.

[image]